# Difficulty creating a new product attribute

Tags: product-attribute

I am trying to create a new product attribute. I fill all of the required fields. When I click on save, I get the following message.

[image]

I'm new at this and trying to create a demo site, so I admit to being clueless. What should I enter here, or did I miss a step somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this filed you have to give **label which is shown in adminpanel.**

**If the frontend label has no value then same admin label  has shown for frontend store**.

Below url help you to understand what attribute is and how its work.

https://trellis.co/blog/managing-attributes-attribute-sets-magento-1-9/

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this answer. Where is this label shown in the admin panel? What field do I have to put it in?

Comment: you have to put label where you have failed msg. this label shown at product edit or create time as label for that field

Comment: for example if this attribute is for informaion , and here you put `Information` as label then for that field in adminside `information` comes as label

Comment: You are always welcome @Dave :)

Comment: Hey @Dave What Happen Why you Unmark My answer??

Comment: Sorry. I made some kind of mistake with the Android app. I'll fix it.

Comment: It should be fixed now.

Comment: Ok, Appreciate.

Comment: I think the Android app is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to name the new attribute. This name can be anything you want, it just has to be unique (as far as i understand it). This name then gets used when you are editing the attribute sets in the admin.

[image]

You're not doing something wrong, or have anything broken. Just has to have a name to be able to be used correctly.

Comment: Yeah, i saw that after i posted. : )